# ImportError: cannot import name 'FileStorage' from 'werkzeug'

Tags: python, python-2.7, werkzeug, connexion

We are getting:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/connexion/decorators/validation.py", line 9, in <module>
    from werkzeug import FileStorage
```

since we are working with Python 2.7.x 
upgrading `connexion==2.6.0` is not an option.

Answer (score 10):

Python 2.7.x:

Installing `Werkzeug==0.16.1`
after the `connexion` installation solved this issue.

Python 3.x:

`connexion==2.6.0`

Comment: I think this will work. But has a oppening issue https://github.com/zalando/connexion/issues/1149 with this problem

Comment: Python 3.7.x can upgrade the connexion version, Python 2.7.x requires the above fix

Answer (score 6):

Just add `Werkzeug==0.16.1` to your `requirements.txt`. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Not relevant for OP but for people landing here with a more recent version of Werkzeug (i.e. `2.x`) released after `May 2021`, do:

```py
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage
```